# why does relative positioning make a horizontal scroll bar?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to position some text/pictures using position relative, however when using relative, it creates a scroll bar eventhough the content is not over there. Is there a way to not have it do this other than overflow:hidden?

the css for the object is

```
body {background-image:url('../images/logo1.jpg');

    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;

}

body {color:black;}
a, a:visited { 
color:white; 
text-decoration:none;

}

div#header {
font-size:280%;
float:right;
text-decoration:underline;
}


#nav {
margin:0;
padding:0;
background:#808259 url(nav_bg.jpg) 0 0 repeat-x;
width:100%;
border:1px solid #42432d;
border-width:1px 0;
position:absolute;
top:100px;
left:0px;
font-size:175%;

}
    #nav li {
        display:inline;
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
    }
    #nav a:link,
    #nav a:visited {
        color:#000;
        background:#b2b580;
        padding:20px 40px 4px 10px;
        float:left;
        width:auto;
        border-right:1px solid #42432d;
        text-decoration:none;
        font:bold 1em/1em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        text-transform:uppercase;
        text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #555;
    }
    #nav a:hover,
    #nav a:focus {
        color:#fff;
        background:#727454;
    }
    #nav li:first-child a {
        border-left:1px solid #42432d;
    }
    #home #nav-home a,
    #about #nav-about a,
    #archive #nav-archive a,
    #lab #nav-lab a,
    #reviews #nav-reviews a,
    #contact #nav-contact a {
        background:#e35a00;
        color:#fff;
        text-shadow:none;
    }
    #home #nav-home a:hover,
    #about #nav-about a:hover,
    #archive #nav-archive a:hover,
    #lab #nav-lab a:hover,
    #reviews #nav-reviews a:hover,
    #contact #nav-contact a:hover {
        background:#e35a00;
    }
    #nav a:active {
        background:#e35a00;
        color:#fff;
        font-size:150%;
    }

div.logo
img {
position:absolute;
left:0;
top:0;
}
div#support {
text-align:center;
font-size:250%;
color:#CC3300;
position:relative;
top:90px;
left:34%;
text-decoration:underline;
font-weight:bold;
}

div#photo 
img{
margin-top:7%;
margin-left:30%;
}
p#follow {
position:relative;
left:50%;
top:-40px;
font-size:250%;
color:white;
text-decoration:underline;
font-weight:bold;
margin-top:5
}



div#facebook 
img{
position:relative;
left:50%;
top:-40px;
}

div#sitemap {
font-size:200%;
text-decoration:underline;
font-weight:bold;
color:white;
position:relative;
left:600px; 
top:-200px;
}

ul#site {
font-size:175%;
margin-top:-10%;
margin-left: 33%;
padding-left: 0;
color:white;
}

@media (min-width : 1300px) 
and (max-width : 1400px) {

div#support {
text-align:center;
font-size:150%;
color:#CC3300;
position:relative;
top:90px;
left:60%;
text-decoration:underline;
font-weight:bold;
width:40%;

}
div#photo {
margin-top:3%;
height:50%;
width:50%;
}

div#sitemap {
font-size:200%;
text-decoration:underline;
font-weight:bold;
color:white;
position:relative;
left:400px; 
top:-200px;
}
div#facebook 
img{
position:relative;
left:50%;
top:-50px;
}
ul#site {
font-size:175%;
margin-top:-13%;
margin-left: 33%;
color:white;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

If you are trying to position text, it likely has a 100% width (as block elements do). You may not be able to see it, but there is a good chance that by putting `left: 800px;` on your element, it is pushing its bounds out, past the edge of the screen.

This does not happen when using absolute positioning as it basically tells everything to ignore the space that the element takes up.

You could try making sure all of the elements you are positioning are set to either `display: inline;` or `display: inline-block;`, and/or setting a width on the element that you know will keep it contained to the width of the screen.

Comment: ah the width thing worked, thanks a bunch, always was wondering why that happened. Do you recommend relative over absolute? I like absolute for some reason but many dont i guess. It seems to work well and not break the page on zoom in/out

Comment: There should be no preference, each one serves a purpose, and should be chosen based on circumstance. The general recommendation is to use relative over absolute simply because people abuse absolute positioning when it is not needed, and often create problems for themselves. Absolute positioning takes elements out of the page flow, which can complicate layouts, and confuse people. Sometimes it is necessary to use it though, and so it is not wrong to do so.

Comment: i know this is different question, but I have this contact form with "text area" for the message. is there a way to expand the rows/cols in css or only in the html? I tried doing textarea {...} but no luck.

Comment: Ok so for some reason, this CSS I wrote, is having a huge horizontal scroll bar, I will post the CSS above, but for some reason, I dont see whats causing it, as I tried addings widths but that did nothelp.

Comment: does `div#sitemap` have a width? Because it is being pushed over quite a bit. If that's not it, then I am not sure. I would need to see the site itself, or a jsfiddle with the problem re-created.